# How do you detect scrolling in a framework7's virtual-list?

Tags: html-framework-7

I would like to prevent accidental clicks from happening while scrolling a virtual-list. Preventing clicks can be done by returning false at `preroute` function or set `e.preventDefault()`.

**However, detecting scrolling on framework7 does not seems to be straightforward.**

I have tried the following methods to detect scrolling:

1. Use `window.onscroll = scrollFunction`.
2. Listen to scroll event. 
   And also attempt to listen to any scroll event on document using `$$(document).on('scroll')` and also tried `$$('.virtual-list).on('scroll')`. But to no avail.

If anyone out there, who has already solved this issue, please let know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in framework7 virtual-list is just collection , so virtual list need parent container which can be attached with scroll capability. In framework7 ,scroll list capability is rely on "infinite-scroll"

http://framework7.io/docs/infinite-scroll.html